# Custom mySQL column now showing when executing query

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables.

```
== Table structure for table all_tasks

|------
|Column|Type|Null|Default
|------
|id|int(11)|No|
|name|text|No|


|1|Task 1
|2|Task2
|3|Task 3
|4|Task 4
|5|Task 5
== Table structure for table task_list

|id|int(11)|No|
|task_list|varchar(50)|No|
== Dumping data for table task_list

|1|1,2,3
```

First table (all_taska) contains all tasks for my application, and second table got list of tasks from first table.

Second table got column `task_list` that is in array format (1,2,3,4,5)

I want to create `<select> <option>` element with all tasks from first table with tag selected that is insde "`task_list`" array from second table. Problem is that query result fails to return costom column ("Selected" in query).

Does someone knows where's the problem?

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, IF(a.id IN b.task_list, 'no selected', 'selected') as Selected
FROM all_tasks as a LEFT JOIN task_list as b ON a.id IN (b.task_list)
```

Comment: Storing a group of data inside a column is a data integrity error

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `IN` operator for checking conditions in `varchar`s. If you want to implement many-to-many relationship, you can use the following scheme:

```
create table task_list (list_id int not null, task_id int not null)
```

Using this scheme, your query can be implemented the following way:

```
select t.list_id, t.id, t.name, 
       if (tl.list_id is not null, 'selected', 'no selected') as Selected  
from task_list tl right 
     join 
         (select distinct  list_id, id, name from all_tasks join task_list) as t 
     on t.list_id = tl.list_id and t.id = tl.task_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You never should store data as comma-separated string, you should think of normalization. However in this case you can use as

```
select 
t1.id , 
t1.name, 
case 
  when t2.id is not null then 'selected' else 'no selected' 
end as `selected` 
from all_tasks t1 
left join task_list t2 on find_in_set(t1.id,t2.task_list) > 0 ;
```